# CiviCRM Extension MS Office 365

Tags: wordpress, extension

we are using 5.4.21 based on WordPress and we are using the extension MS Office 365 Release 1.

We are following the instruction of the readme (https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/msoffice365/-/blob/main/README.md), but we have the problem that we can´t find where to download the manifest file.

Could you please help us?

Thanks

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a manifest exists, the app must be created in the Azure UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The Azure App is created and connected to CiviCRM.

But i can´t find the Manifest für der MS AddIn installation.